# styled-components error 'cannot read property of undefined' prop that is being passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm passing a `defaultColors` object to a `styled-components` button element, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to see this object.

```
const ButtonPrimary = styled(Button)`
  background-color: ${({ defaultColors }) => defaultColors.primary ?? "blue"};
  color: ${({ defaultColors }) => defaultColors?.secondary ?? "orange"};
  width: 5rem;
  height: 3rem;
`;
```

It can't see neither `defaultColors.primary` not `defaultColors.secondary` because it's as if defaultColors isn't being passed.

If I were to, in another component, pass `defaultColors` to `ButtonPrimary`, then it would see it.. but I obviously do not want to pass that object every single time I use this button.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Edit Styled-components]

Comment: styled-components can only access props that are actually passed to it. ButtonPrimary is a custom styled component of your Button, and ButtonPrimary is not receiving any props in your example. Your Button has the detaultColors, but your ButtonPrimary does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In styled-components you can use `WhatEver.defaultProps`, like:

```js
Button.defaultProps = {
  defaultColors: {
    primary: "black",
    secondary: "white"
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

updated [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-frost-9vpqo?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I ended up using their ThemeProvider, but this would work just as well.